# Trying to make a weather program in C#, but it won't bring back anything except the country code from the API

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, weather-api, openweathermap

So this code is supposed to show the min/max temperatures, wind speed, humidity and country code if I press a button. However, it only brings back the country code and I have no idea why. It doesn't show any errors, but when I press the button that's all that happens. If anyone could look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string uri = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Seoul&mode=xml&appid=78dff84492be32f8b4f77692904607a1");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);


            WebClient client = new WebClient();


            string maxTemp = (string)doc.Descendants("temperature.max").FirstOrDefault();
            string minTemp = (string)doc.Descendants("temperature.min").FirstOrDefault();

            string maxWindm = (string)doc.Descendants("wind.speed.unit").FirstOrDefault();
            string humidity = (string)doc.Descendants("humidity.value").FirstOrDefault();

            string country = (string)doc.Descendants("country").FirstOrDefault();


            txtmaxtemp.Text = maxTemp;
            txtmintemp.Text = minTemp;

            txtwindm.Text = maxWindm;
            txthumidity.Text = humidity;

            txtcountry.Text = country;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just looked at the URL in the browser and the data is there, I think you have to work on you "temperature.max" etc... Not sure that's correct. Put a breakpoint and work on that in the debugger.

Comment: I think that's the problem as well, but in this link https://openweathermap.org/current#current_XML that's what it says, so I'm really confused what I'm supposed to put.

Comment: This is XML parsing. I added the proper Tags for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML for the given uri actually looks like this:

```
<current>
  <city id="1835848" name="Seoul">
    <coord lon="126.98" lat="37.57"/>
    <country>KR</country>
    <timezone>32400</timezone>
    <sun rise="2019-12-06T22:33:04" set="2019-12-07T08:13:43"/>
  </city>
  <temperature value="270.15" min="266.15" max="274.15" unit="kelvin"/>
  <humidity value="86" unit="%"/>
  <pressure value="1029" unit="hPa"/>
  <wind>
    <speed value="1.25" unit="m/s" name="Calm"/>
    <gusts/>
    <direction value="302" code="WNW" name="West-northwest"/>
  </wind>
  <clouds value="90" name="overcast clouds"/>
  <visibility value="10000"/>
  <precipitation mode="no"/>
  <weather number="804" value="overcast clouds" icon="04n"/>
  <lastupdate value="2019-12-07T12:41:00"/>
</current>
```

While looking at the `country`-*node* you can see that it's an xml-node. Contrary the `min`- and `max`-temperatures are *attributes* of the `temperature`-node.

You can access attributes like this:

```
string maxTemp = (string)doc.Descendants("temperature").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("max").Value;
```

Please note, that this will work but it's quite prone to a `NullReferenceException` as I'm blindly utilizing `FirstOrDefault()` ;-)

Comment: Oh my god, this fixed my problem. Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for  hours..... And yeah, I did get a NullReferenceException error when I tried it with the wind, but it's progress haha

Comment: It's a good idea to describe a problem to someone else if you're stuck for too long. More often than not it's just a small detail that's missing but one simply doesn't notice it :-)